# text-mining: Determine to which noun a verb refers?

Tags: python, text, nlp, analytics, text-mining

I'm trying to find a package/library which enables me to determine to which noun a verb refers (in Python):

> The man was walking down the street

That this will give me a result like walking *refers to* man. 
I tried to use [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) however as far as I could find out I can only tag the wordst as nouns/verbs etc. but cannot infer any references from this.

**Question**
Are there any packages which are capable to do the above?

Comment: If you downvote please say WHY instead of just downvoting

Comment: it doesn't seem to be an easy problem, not sure if there is any library with such functionality

Comment: Upvoting. The problem might be difficult but the question asks for a library that already solve it.

Comment: I agree, downvoting should be followed by a comment justifying the downvote.

Comment: @CodeNoob If an answer is correct, mark it as such please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is explore the syntactic dependencies among words. For that, you need to parse your text with a syntactic parser.

Since you want to know the references between nouns and verbs you will need to do two things.

You need to get the part-of-speech tags associated to each words (i.e. the morphology associated to each word, wether it's a ADJ, DET, VERB, NOUN, etc.) then you want to select the ones tagged as verbs and nouns.

Then, you want to look at which other words they connect with, I think mostly you will want to explore the 'nsubj' dependency.

[spaCy](https://spacy.io/) is a NLP library for Python that performs syntactic parsing, and also has a on-line demo, if you want to try it out, check:

https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/

Here is the output for the example you gave:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou! Do you know a simple code example which extracts all verbs connected to a specific noun?

Comment: that's too specific, take a bit of time and learn how to use spaCy, here is a good tutorial: https://nicschrading.com/project/Intro-to-NLP-with-spaCy/